# c# states stored procedure parameter is expected when its in the code

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, execute

I keep getting this exception but I don't know why

> Procedure or function 'InsertNewUser' expects parameter '@Username', which was not supplied

Any ideas?

```
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "InsertNewUser";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterName: "@Username", sqlDbType: SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UsernameTextBox.Text.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterName: "@Email", sqlDbType: SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmailTextBox.Text.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterName: "@Password", sqlDbType: SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PasswordTextBox.Text.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterName: "@FirstName", sqlDbType: SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FirstNameTextBox.Text.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SecondName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SecondNameTextbox.Text.ToString();

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Registration Successful");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Registration Failed");
}
```

Comment: You forgot to set the cmd.CommandType to CommandType.StoredProcedure. Also you don't need to call ToString on a string property. It is just useless

Comment: Don't forget to dispose cmd/con.

Comment: You can get this error message if your parameter value is null and the procedure does not define a default value. If null is what you want (I doubt it in this case) you need to use `DBNull.Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "InsertNewUser";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; //<---  Specify your command type

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", UsernameTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", EmailTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PasswordTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstNameTextBox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondName", SecondNameTextbox.Text);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Registration Successful");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Registration Failed");
}
```

Comment: AddWithValue is well known to be a performace killer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had no idea on the potential run-time costs of the conversions.

Comment: It is not just the conversions but  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your code...

You are giving stored procedure name and also passing parameters but not telling it, it is a stored procedure not a text query.

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```